Prononciation de /ɛ̃/ comme [æ̃] et de /ɑ̃/ comme [ɒ̃] en français parisien
Bonjour,
J'ai une question concernant la prononciation de certaines voyelles nasales en français.
Comme on le sait, en API la prononciation de ain, in et ein se transcrit /ɛ̃/, tandis que celle de an et en se transcrit en /ɑ̃/.
Cependant, le Wiktionnaire indique ce qui suit :
« L’API du français traditionnellement utilisé reflète une prononciation vieille de plus d’un siècle. »
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Prononciation/fran%C3%A7ais#:~:text=L'API%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%20traditionnellement,mais%20avec%20des%20prononciations%20diff%C3%A9rentes.
Il décrit ensuite la prononciation de chacun des deux comme suit :
Sur /ɛ̃/ en notant la perte de distinction entre /ɛ̃/ et /œ̃/, « en français parisien, la distinction est déjà perdue, et /œ̃/ se prononce comme /ɛ̃/. La prononciation actuelle est plus ouverte que [ɛ̃], plutôt [æ̃]. »
Sur le changement de [ɑ̃] (traditionnel) en [ɒ̃] (moderne) en français parisien, il écrit :
« Originairement une voyelle nasale ouverte postérieure non arrondie, elle est devenue une voyelle nasale ouverte postérieure arrondie. »
Je trouve ces déclarations très pertinentes. Pour moi, non francophone, /ɛ̃/ sonne comme [æ̃] et /ɑ̃/ sonne comme [ɒ̃].
En faisant des recherches sur Internet à ce sujet, j'ai trouvé quelques personnes qui ont écrit des pensées similaires à la description ci-dessus. Par exemple, la mention suivante (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whence-the-nasals-vowels-in-french.1437092/) :

This is how I [portugais] hear the Parisian vowels:
/ɛ̃/ ~ /œ̃/ as [æ̃] or even [ã] (ã as a front vowel, not the central
[ä]). (It sounds like a fronter version of Brazilian Portuguese ã in
rã, maçã; raisin sounds like rezã to me, two vowels in this word are
nothing alike  )
/ɑ̃/ as [ɒ̃ ] or even [ɔ̃] (it sounds like Brazilian Portuguese ó in
avó but nasalized)

Ces descriptions me semblent correspondre à mes propres impressions sur ces sons.
Cependant, le problème pour moi est que ces affirmations ne se trouvent pas dans les grammaires traditionnelles, ni dans Le Bon usage, ni dans la Grammaire méthodique du français. Il en va de même pour les grammaires destinées aux personnes qui apprennent le français comme langue étrangère.
L'ouvrage auquel le Wiktionnaire fait référence comme source des explications citées plus haut est L. Canepari, A Handbook of Pronunciation, 2005. Je n'ai pas pu le lire moi-même, mais il semble qu'il s'agisse d'une sorte de catalogue contenant des notations précises en API de la prononciation des principales langues européennes.
Existe-t-il des ouvrages fiables qui peuvent m'aider à ce propos ?
Par ailleurs, que pensez-vous de la prononciation de /ɛ̃/ et /ɑ̃/ ?
Je vous remercie par avance.

La prononciation du français, y compris celle prescrite aux enseignants des écoles primaires, change très rapidement. Je croirais volontiers que les ouvrages fiables ne le sont que pour l'année où ils ont été édités et le domaine géographique dont ils reflètent l'étude. Même le français du WWW n'est pas celui que j'ai appris à enregistrer sur magnétophone.

1- Les livres de grammaire ne donnent en général que très peu d'information sur la prononciation. 2- IPA or not IPA that is the question. L'utilisation de l'API est régulièrement remise en cause et certains font à leur sauce, on peut s'y perdre.

3- Canepari critique l'API traditionnel et s'en éloigne, il a créé sa propre notation issue de l'API  CANIPA.  Some academic reviews of Canepari's book: 1,  2 (p.12). On Canepari's website you can download pdf files concerning French including French Pronunciation & Accents (PDF→other languages →F-K). Companion to A Handbook of Pronunciation is A handbook of phonetics.

You could try Linguistics for questions on phonetics  and pronunciation.

Lorsque la prononciation d'une langue change, on peut soit changer les symboles API, soit les conserver. L'anglais a changé les symboles API, ce qui a introduit de la confusion. Et le français les a conservé, ce que a également introduit de la confusion.

La notation phonémique sert à identifier et différencier des mots du point de vue des locuteurs d'une langue. La réalisation des phonèmes en phones est une affaire individuelle et des variations plus ou moins importantes peuvent se faire entendre entre locuteurs, régions, etc.
Quand des variations ne sont par pertinentes pour une oreille native, elles sont regroupées sous un même phonème. Les voyelles nasales répertoriées pour le français sont au nombre de quatre, mais pour une partie importante des locuteurs, la spécificité de la troisième /œ̃/ est inaudible.

Il est très possible que les réalisations les plus courantes de ces trois ou quatre nasales ne correspondent plus aux phones des symboles choisis et c'est une partie de ce qui motive cette question.
La phonologie du portugais, cité dans un lien de la question, inclus elle aussi des nasales mais elle est beaucoup plus riche avec cinq nasales simples et six diphtongues nasales :


Il n'est donc pas étonnant que pour une oreille habituée à distinguer les phones du portugais ou d'autres langues à voyelles nasales, la classification française porte à confusion.
